# Rails 4 validation Issue: form dosn't submit after validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

OK. I've been learning Rails in the past weeks, and I'm really a noob.

I'm working on a Hotel booking system. The idea is to load a form, validate the fields, and save the data. If there isn't any validation error, the reservation is properly saved.  But if the form shows some validation errors, the submit button stop working (I mean, I can fix the text so the validation error doesn't pop up, but once fixed, I can not submit the new data).

this is the Model:

```
class Reserva < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :fecha_ingreso, :fecha_salida, presence: { message: " es un campo obligatorio" },
                            format: { with: /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/ , message: "Debe utilizar formato dd/mm/aaaa" }

  validates :canti_hues, :tipo_hab, :email, :peticion, presence: { message: " es un campo obligatorio" }

  validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }



end
```

this is the controller:

```
  before_action :set_reserva, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reservas
  # GET /reservas.json
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      @reservas = Reserva.all
    else
      redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action => 'ingresar'
    end     
  end

  # GET /reservas/1
  # GET /reservas/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /reservas/new
  def new
    @reserva = Reserva.new
  end

  # GET /reservas/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reservas
  # POST /reservas.json
  def create
    @reserva = Reserva.new(reserva_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reserva.save
        format.html { redirect_to @reserva, notice: 'La reserva fue creada exitosamente.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reserva }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @reserva.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reservas/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reservas/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reserva.update(reserva_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @reserva, notice: 'Reserva was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reserva }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @reserva.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reservas/1
  # DELETE /reservas/1.json
  def destroy
    @reserva.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reservas_url, notice: 'Reserva was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_reserva
      @reserva = Reserva.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def reserva_params
      params.require(:reserva).permit(:fecha_ingreso, :fecha_salida, :canti_hues, :tipo_hab, :email, :peticion)
    end
end
```

And this is the _form rendered in the view:

```
    <%= form_for(@reserva) do |f| %>
      <% if @reserva.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@reserva.errors.count, "error") %> encontrado:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @reserva.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div align='center'>
        <table border='1'>
            <td width=300 align='center'>   
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :fecha_ingreso %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :fecha_ingreso %>
              </div>
             <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :fecha_salida %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :fecha_salida %>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :cantidad_de_huespedes %><br>
                <%= f.number_field :canti_hues %>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :tipo_de_habitación %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :tipo_hab %>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :email %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :email %>
              </div>
              <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :peticiones_especiales %><br>
                <%= f.text_area :peticion %>
              </div>
              <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </table>  

    <% end %>
```

Why can't I submit if the validation errors has been fixed?? 
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Does it show anything in the console i.e. javascript related? When you say the button doesn't work do you mean its not clickable?

Comment: please paste the related `javascript`

Comment: Please paste what error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

I typed your code in my project - when I passed in the form:

```
fecha_ingreso: 22/22/1991
fecha_salida: 23/02/2222
canti_hues: 1
tipo_hab: abc
email: sample@example.com
peticion: abc
```

Everything passes. And the record is saved properly.

Validation error `can't be blank` appears under `canti_hues` attribute when you try to type in the field other value than number. This happens, because non-number value from `number_field` is not sent to controller at all.

Other thing, you need to do is be sure that you typed value in correct format to other fields.

However, in the code above there is nothing that could rise any unexpected problems. If you have no javascript to correspond with this form, the only solution is bad data.

PS: **Quick advice** - in rails application always name resources and attributes in english. Rails have mounted mechanizm to pluralization and singularisation, and if you will want to use it in the future, you will have to refactor most of your code.